# Container-fluid in navbar yii2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii2

I am starting learning yii2,

I want to create layout like this : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-bootstrap-index.html

I am little confused, how yii write the bootstrap nav.
I want to create nav to container-fluid. 
I have a write in html on codeigniter like this :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo site_url('admin'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <?php echo $this->config->item('erp_title'); ?></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Export</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-anchor"></i> Import</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-archive"></i> Inventory</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gavel"></i> Operation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Marketing</a></li>

            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Keuangan </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Accounting </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Persum </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ship"></i> Armada</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> IT</a></li>

        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <?php print_r($this->ion_auth->user()->row()->username); ?> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <?php
                    if ($this->ion_auth->is_admin()) {
                        ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/groups'); ?>">Groups</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/users'); ?>">Users</a></li>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/user/profile'); ?>">Profile page</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/user/logout'); ?>">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>

            </li>

        </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```

How to create navbar to container-fluid in yii2 ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The correct way to make the container fluid is to adjust your Navbar's configuration in your NavBar::begin declaration like so:

```
NavBar::begin([
   'innerContainerOptions' => ['class' => 'container-fluid'],
]);
```

Comment: @Fadly Dzil If you found this answer useful, would you consider marking it as the correct answer?  Thanks.

Comment: For good look on lists and forms I had to change this part too
`
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'navbar-default navbar-fixed-top',
        ],
`
to
`
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'navbar-default',
        ],
`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
use yii\bootstrap\Nav;



NavBar::begin([
        'brandLabel' => 'NavBar Test',
        'innerContainerOptions' => ['class' => 'container-fluid'],
        'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
        'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar-inverse',
    ],
]);
echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => [
        ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
        ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
    ],
]);
NavBar::end();
```

[enter link description here](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/doc/api/2.2/yii-bootstrap-nav)

also for menu only:

```
use yii\widgets\Menu;

echo Menu::widget([
    'items' => [
        // Important: you need to specify url as 'controller/action',
        // not just as 'controller' even if default action is used.
        ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['site/index']],
        // 'Products' menu item will be selected as long as the route is 'product/index'
        ['label' => 'Products', 'url' => ['product/index'], 'items' => [
            ['label' => 'New Arrivals', 'url' => ['product/index', 'tag' => 'new']],
            ['label' => 'Most Popular', 'url' => ['product/index', 'tag' => 'popular']],
        ]],
        ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['site/login'], 'visible' => Yii::$app->user->isGuest],
    ],
]);
```

[enter link description here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-menu)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proper layout  adding a new layout  views\layouts\

eg: wide.php

Looking  to (copying)  main.php layout you can change it expecially  the part immediatelly above   changing container with container-fluid

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div>    
        <?php echo Breadcrumbs::widget(['links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [], ]);   ?>       
        <?php echo Alert::widget(); ?>

        <?= $content ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

then you can change in controller the layout in use for the action this way

```
public function actionYourAction()
{

   ........
   $this->layout = 'wide';
   return $this->render('your_view', [
        ......
        'model'                 => $model,
       .....
    ]);
}
```