# How to give active class to clicked button in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I am a new member in Yii2. I integrated new template with by default Yii2 advanced template. I need to use active class to clicked menu from side bar. Below my code. How can I do it? Please help me

```
<li class="">
   <?= Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-education"></i><span>Суд жараёни</span>', ['law1/']) ?>
</li>
<li class="">
   <?= Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i><span>МИБ</span>', ['law2/']) ?>
</li>
<li class="">
   <?= Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ruble"></i><span>Прократура</span>', ['law3/']) ?>
</li>
<li class="">
   <?= Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bitcoin"></i><span>Банк</span>', ['law4/']) ?>
</li>
```

Comment: If you mean menu navigation, go to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020600/container-fluid-in-navbar-yii2/51804588#51804588).

Answer (score 0):

**Some Simple Approaches**

You can compare the `controller/route/action` to the `URL` and if they match add an active class with a yii2 helper:

1. Simple add class to html link:

   ```
   <?php
   use yii\helpers\Html;
   $controller =  Yii::$app->controller->id;
   $options = ['class' => ['btn btn-md btn-default']];
   if ($controller == 'batch') {
       Html::addCssClass($options, ['active']);
   }
   echo $link = Html::a('SomeLink', ['batch/view'], $options);
   echo $link = Html::a('SomeLink', ['batch/view'],);
   ?>
   ```
2. If using a nav widget, you can leverage the `active` and `visible` properties:

   ```
   <?php
   use mdm\admin\components\Helper;
   $controller =  Yii::$app->controller->id;
   echo kartik\sidenav\SideNav::widget([
       'type' => SideNav::TYPE_DEFAULT,
       'items' => [
           [
               'url' => ['supplier/index'],
               'label' => 'Suppliers',
               //'icon' => 'th-list',
               'active' => $controller == 'supplier',
               'visible' => Helper::checkRoute('supplier/index'),
           ],
           [
               'url' => ['site/index'],
               'label' => 'Sites',
               //'icon' => 'th-list',
               'active' => $controller == 'site',
               'visible' => Helper::checkRoute('site/index'),
           ],
       ],
   ]);
   ?>
   ```